# C programm to read characters between two '*'

Tags: c

I want the programm to read the characters that are between two  stars and if there are not two stars, it must print a respective message. For example if the input is `1abc*D2Efg_#!*34567`, the output is `between first tow stars (letters : 4, digits:1, other:3)` any help will be appreciated

```
int main()
{
  int ch,lowercase_lett,digits,other,uppercase_lett,asterisk;
  lowercase_lett = 0;
  uppercase_lett = 0;
  digits = 0;
  other = 0;
  asterisk = 0;
  printf("enter characters : ");
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
  {
    if(ch == '*')
    {
      asterisk++;
    }
    if(asterisk < 2)
    {
      printf("\ntwo asterisks not found\n");
    }
    else
    {
      if(ch>='a' && ch <= 'z')
      {
        lowercase_lett++;
      }
      else if(ch>='A' && ch <= 'Z')
      {
        uppercase_lett++;
      }
      else if(ch >='0' && ch <= '9')
      {
        digits++;
      }
      else
      {
        other++;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n%d letters %d digits and %d other" , lowercase_lett+uppercase_lett,digits,other);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you find some error on the outputs produced by your algorithm?

Comment: You could use `ctype.h`'s category functions instead of a range and it would probably make your code even more readable.

Comment: @Maf no errors, just not desired output

Comment: I could test it and I see now. I corrected some lines of you code in my answer. You were almost there, but this condition `if(asterisk < 2)` is critical for your problem because it is supposed to happen only when you want to stop your search (i.e. `break`)

Comment: Please use a consistent indention style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, but your code contains some lines in wrong places.

Look at my solution. I just tested and it works for your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int ch;
    int lowercase_lett = 0;
    int uppercase_lett = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int other = 0;
    int asterisks = 0;

    printf("Enter characters: ");

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {

        if(asterisks == 2){
            break; //End the search
        }

        else if(ch == '*'){
            asterisks++; //Increment until we have 2 *
        }
        
        else if(asterisks == 1){
            if((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')){
                lowercase_lett++;
            }
            else if((ch >='A') && (ch <= 'Z')){
                uppercase_lett++;
            }
            else if((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')){
                digits++;
            }
            else{
                other++;
            }
        }
    }
     
    if (asterisks >= 2){
        printf("\n%d letters %d digits and %d other" , lowercase_lett+uppercase_lett,digits,other);
    }
    else{
        printf("\ntwo asterisks not found\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked exactly as i wanted thx a lot!!!!!. I cant upvote you yet though, i have rep lower than 15 sry

Comment: I'm glad I coud help. I just refactored the code to be more organized and clear for everyone. Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: Note that `break; //End the search` won't work for some input like `hoge*fuga**foo` because there are two consequtive asterisks (2nd and 3rd) in this case and `asterisks` will become 3 before checking against the condition `asterisks == 2`. Also "two asterisks not found" will be printed in this case while (more than) two asterisks are in the input.

Comment: Yeah, I have to invert the conditions as I had before the code refactoring.

Comment: In this case you won't have that issue any longer since only a single `asterisk` will be counted from your consecutive example.

Comment: Now your code will count all characters after the first asterisk without checking if the character is an asterisk anymore. Then it will print "two asterisks not found" for all cases because `asterisks` cannot become `2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your point @MikeCAT. I also changed the condition out of the loop as `if (asterisks >= 2)` to handle the cases where there's an asterisk at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Count characters when exactly one asterisk has been found. Functions in [`ctype.h`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/ctype.h.0p.html) are useful to determine the type of characters.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    int ch,lowercase_lett,digits,other,uppercase_lett,asterisk;
    lowercase_lett = 0;
    uppercase_lett = 0;
    digits = 0;
    other = 0;
    asterisk = 0;
    printf("enter characters : ");
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
      if(ch == '*')
      {
        asterisk++;
        if(asterisk>=2)
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      else if(asterisk==1)
      {
        if(islower(ch))
        {
            lowercase_lett++;
        }
        else if(isupper(ch))
        {
            uppercase_lett++;
        }else if(isdigit(ch)){
            digits++;
        }else{
            other++;
        }
      }
    }
    if(asterisk<2)
    {
      printf("\ntwo asterisks not found\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\n%d letters %d digits and %d other" , lowercase_lett+uppercase_lett,digits,other);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: although it did print whatever was typed after the star, i want the code to print only characters that are between two stars

Comment: @h3rmitpurple Added code to deal with the cases in which there are less than two asterisks.

Comment: This solution contains an issue: If you have `two asterisks` at the very beginning of the string and the string `length` is very big, then you keep iterating for nothing. Fix it by adding a `break` to the loop when the two `asterisks` are already found.